# Is there a portable version of OneNote available/comming

Tags: onenote

Is there a portable version of OneNote available/coming, to use from a USB drive/library.

Where onenote.com webapp is a no-need-to-install option, but doesn't work offline

Solutions I'm thinking of: HTML5 offline app (no GPO's that will stop it), or an app-v/thinapp version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we have no plans for a portable version.